# AlarmManager - Wake with WiFi?

Tags: android

So I've created the majority of my application but I am having an issue with power saving applications interfering with it. I use the AlarmManager to run a piece of code that send information to a server every x minutes (minimum 1h), the main issue I am having is that power managers are disabling with WiFi because the device is sleeping.

What's the most effective way to ensure WiFi is available at wakeup? Is it to simply enable WiFi and reconnect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an other way to your solution is to listen for the connection_changed intents. That way you know there is a connection to the internet and you can upload.

You can also enable WiFi but you will need permissions for that: (I guess these)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
```

Haven't tried it but this should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is, I wake the phone, acquire a wake lock and execute my code, the upload needs to be run after the code execution as I don't want to run the application constantly (would waste battery).